# React freeze for 1~2 seconds when use map in a state array of 168 objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My problem occurs when I try to update and property from a state array of objects after executing a `axios.put`.

That's my code:

States - useEffect

```js
//...
const [volunteers, setVolunteers] = useState([]);
//...
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadVolunteers() {
      api
        .get('volunteers')
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data.map(volunteer => ({
            ...volunteer,
            notChecked: volunteer.confirmed === null,
            confirmedText: volunteer.confirmed ? 'Deferido' : 'Indeferido',
            createdDateFormatted: format(
              parseISO(volunteer.createdAt),
              "d 'de' MMMM'/'yyyy",
              {
                locale: pt,
              }
            ),
          }));
          setVolunteers(data);
        })
        .then(() => {
          api
            .get('departments')
            .then(response => {
              setDepartments(response.data);
              setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(() => {
              toast.error(
                'Ops! Aconteceu algum problema ao buscar as Inscrições. Tente novamente mais tarde e/ou contate o Programador'
              );
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          toast.error(
            'Ops! Aconteceu algum problema ao buscar as Inscrições. Tente novamente mais tarde e/ou contate o Programador'
          );
        });
    }

    if (!isAdmin) {
      history.push('/dashboard');
    }

    loadVolunteers();
    dispatch(changePage('inscricoes'));
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line
//...
```

```js
  const updateDepartment = async (id, department_id) => {
    try {
      await api.put(`volunteers/${id}/department`, {
        department_id,
      });
      setVolunteers(
        volunteers.map(volunteer => {
          if (volunteer.id === id) {
            volunteer.department_id = department_id;
            return volunteer;
          }
          return volunteer;
        })
      );
      toast.success('Departamento atualizado');
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error('Erro ao atualizar departamento');
    }
  };
```

If I remove the `setVolunteers` instruction, this methods runs instantly.

But when I try to do that map in the volunteers array/state, the application freeze for 1~2 seconds.

Why?

Below the rest of the react code iterating the volunteers array.

```js
{volunteers.map((volunteer, index) => (
  <Card
    key={volunteer.id}
    className={classes.card}
    variant="outlined"
  >
    <CardContent>
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="none"
        required
        select
        fullWidth
        id="gender"
        value={volunteer.department_id}
        placeholder="Selecione"
        onChange={e =>
          updateDepartment(volunteer.id, e.target.value)
        }
        label="Selecione seu sexo"
        name="gender"
      >
        {departments.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
            {option.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
      <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
        {volunteer.user.name}
      </Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
        {volunteer.user.phone}
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
        <strong>Líder: </strong>
        {volunteer.user.leader_name}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions className={classes.subActions}>
      {volunteer.notChecked ? (
        <>
          <Button
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            disabled={loadConfirm}
            onClick={() =>
              handleConfirmation(index, volunteer.id, true)
            }
          >
            Deferido
          </Button>
          <Button
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            disabled={loadConfirm}
            onClick={() =>
              handleConfirmation(index, volunteer.id, false)
            }
          >
            Indeferido
          </Button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Button
          size="small"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          disabled
        >
          {volunteer.confirmed ? 'Deferido' : 'Indeferido'}
        </Button>
      )}
      <Button
        size="small"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        className={classes.deny}
        disabled={loadConfirm}
        onClick={() => handleDelete(index, volunteer.id, true)}
      >
        Excluir
      </Button>
    </CardActions>
  </Card>
))}
```

Comment: If you have big set that you try to map, then no wonder JS locks UI to execute your code. Maybe try to move it to async execution?

Comment: In your case, they usually use pagination in order not to receive all the data from the server at once.

Comment: could you provide your `setVolunteers` implementation?

Comment: @Hao-CherHong yes

Comment: Why are you using `async` with `.then()`. Shouldn't you be using `await` in here?

Comment: To check whether it is freezing due to `map()` or `setVolunteers()`, you could do: `setTimeout(() => {const newVolunteers = volunteers.map(...); setTimeout(setVolunteers(newVolunteers))})` to separate the executions of mapping and setVolunteers to 2 render cycle. If the freezing is happening on `setVolunteers()`, it's probably freezing because manipulating too many DOM objects at a time, try to separate that to different cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a callback function to update the state.

Try this.

```
const updateDepartment = async (id, department_id) => {
  try {
    await api.put(`volunteers/${id}/department`, {
      department_id
    });
    setVolunteers(prevState => {
      let Volunteers = prevState.map(volunteer => {
        if (volunteer.id === id) {
          volunteer.department_id = department_id;
          return volunteer;
        }
        return volunteer;
      });
      return Volunteers;
    });
    toast.success("Departamento atualizado");
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error("Erro ao atualizar departamento");
  }
};
```